# How to specify class files with bnd

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

I already successfully used the standalone bnd tool to create an OSGi bundle from a jar file.

Now I would like to create a bundle starting from .class files.
By looking at some of the official bnd documentation I couldn't find anything to do this.
I guess I'm looking for something like `-classpath: output.jar` that could work for .class files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options: Workspace bndtools (includes Gradle build), Standalone Gradle, Maven, and bnd standalone. I strongly prefer the Bndtools workspace model since it is by the most user friendly. Lots of support, full fidelity with gradle without any extra work, interactive debugging, remote debugging, packaging, and active community. It is based on Eclipse.

The following links should be able to get you started:

- Workspace here: https://bndtools.org/
- Bnd manual: https://bnd.bndtools.org/
- v2Archive enRoute (this is not directly supported by OSGi anymore but has a wealth of information how to work with the Bndtools Workspace model) https://v2archive.enroute.osgi.org/book/210-doc.html

**Update**

If you just want to use the bnd command line you're simplifying things a lot but you also have to take care of more things. And you miss the wonderful world of `bndtools` :-(

Even then, you still have a choice to make. bnd can be used to build Workspace model setups. In this case you follow the rules for the bndtools Workspace tutorials etc. In that model, you can use bnd build, compile, and many other commands in the workspace or projects directories.

If you also want to skip those, you end up with a bnd that just generates a JAR from a bnd property file. In that case you must specify all your dependencies with:

```
-classpath bin/,jar/a.jar, jar/b.jar
```

You can then use all the Builder instructions.

```
-includeresource
Private-Package
Export-Package
-exportcontents
...
```

All bundle headers, etc. Most verrification and building should work similar from the Bndtools workspace examples. Of course you miss launching and many other features. However, I've heard of someone that builds a large code base  this way ...

The following URL shows some examples how to use this: https://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/160-jars.html

Comment: I would like to go the bnd standalone route. However I couldn't find any options to use a different directory structure than the default one, which is explained at https://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/125-tour-features.html

Comment: Yes, just with the bnd commandline. I don't use ant, Maven, Gradle... I already have the .class files from javac.

Comment: As you show in the updated answer, does `-classpath bin/` pull in all .class files under `bin`? Recursively?

Comment: Yup. Inside bnd there is the Jar class and you just give it a directory or a jar/zip file and it will worry about the rest.

Comment: I still have to try it, but the -classpath route is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood what you are trying to do, one option could be to set up a maven project and take advantage of the `bnd-maven-plugin` as described [here](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven/bnd-maven-plugin). Basically, it is enough to add the following snippet in the build/plugins section of your pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
    <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>bnd-process</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For a complete example of a maven-based approach you can refer to the OSGi enRoute website: https://enroute.osgi.org/Tutorial/

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to introduce Maven in my project.

Comment: Did you try with bndtools? (no maven but eclipse dependent) https://bndtools.org/tutorial.html